# React Native Xcode recursive header expansion

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, onesignal

I'm having an issue building my React Native iOS app in Xcode.

Here is the error:

> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Users/myNameGoesHere/BobcatPulse/ios/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android/build/tmp/expandedArchives/classes.jar_cakcvq0ql5pup67gndjh8nabd/android/support/v4/hardware/display.

Now this is strange because I see the issue looks like it is happening when Xcode looks into `react-native-onesignal/android/` but according to the header search paths in Xcode it should not be looking there at all? See below:

[image: Screenshot]

Note that I did set `react-native-onesignal/ios/RCTOneSignal` to non-recursive despite what the picture may show.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Also just so you are aware I did set react-native-onesignal/ios/RCTOneSignal to non-recursive despite what the picture may show

Comment: Did you resolve this? and how?